# Prove that a map is a homeomorphism and the inverse is bounded

Tags: metric-spaces, manifolds, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to unravel an obscure passage in a textbook, which states that if $\phi :\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous, bounded and Lipschitz with constant $\varepsilon$ (which is still free to choose) and $A := Df(0)$, where $f$ is smooth map with a hyperbolic fixed point at $0$, then the following statements are true:

1. "It is easy to see the if $\varepsilon$ is small enough then $A+\phi$ is a homeomorphism"
2. $\left\|(A+\phi)^{-1}\right\| \le 1$ with $\|\cdot\|$ the sup-norm.

I don't find it easy to see that the first statement is true, and I also cannot reproduce the second assertion. Does anyone know how to proceed here?

Comment: What does $D_0$ mean? (Differential at the point $0$, maybe?)

Comment: Indeed, hopefully the edited notation is more broadly used ;)

Comment: And what does "hyperbolic fixed point" mean? (Maybe it is widespread, but I don't think I have ever heard it)

Comment: It means that $A$ has no eigenvalues of magnitude $1$

Comment: I suspect that Neumann's series or something like that are being used here. I mean, a typical argument to prove that the matrix $A-\epsilon B$ is invertible if $A$ is invertible and $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small is collecting $A$ to the left and then observing that $I-\epsilon A^{-1}B$ is invertible if the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\epsilon A^{-1}B)^n$$
is convergent. In words, one says that a small linear perturbation to an invertible linear operator yields an invertible linear operator. The argument used here is probably a nonlinear version of this principle.